# Помогите разобраться.В выборе фреймворка

Tags: php, framework

Прошу прощения если вопрос из разряда "холивара". 
В связи не большим опытом с фреймворками. 2 самописных, Laravel и YII 2, я не могу судить объективно в выборе. На проекте утверждают что самописные фреймворки лучше а все остальные перегружены ненужным функционалом,необъективно заумные и медленные.

А мне все же кажется что для каждой задачи своё и самописное как ни крути хуже будет.

Как быть да и кто прав. Хочется новое учить, разбираться а не  в самописном сидеть.

*P.S. если вопрос не в тему сайта удалю, без вопросов.*

Comment: Если хотите новое учить и разбираться - учите и разбирайтесь. А потом найдите работу с теми технологиями, которые вам интересны. Будет ли это ларавел, yii или еще что-то

Answer (score 3):

Все правы. Тут вечная борьба частного решения с общим.

Фреймворки призваны решать общие проблемы и поэтому:

- Вносят некоторый оверхед в работе
- Загоняют в рамки и требуют адаптации решения задачи к фреймворку.

Зато эти общие проблемы они решают хорошо, ведь их пишут и тестируют люди, которые в этом понимают. А еще комьюнити поддерживает качество фрейворка.

Самописный же фреймворк может максимально подходить под задачу и иметь минимальный оверхед. Но готовы ли вы поддерживать свой фреймворк, развивать, тестировать так же качественно? Скорее всего нет. Это нужно не один фреймворк написать, чтобы руку набить, да и все равно нужно время на это.

Вот и приходится выбирать между готовым и своим. Кто может позволить себе или имеет необходимость - пишет свои фреймворки. Кто не может - берет готовые.

Писать самому фреймворки крайне полезно для общего развития. Это дает понимание общего устройства. Но для работы лучше использовать готовые.

Какие?

Тут сложнее - фреймворки есть мини, мидл и так далее. Хотя тут субъективная грань. И чем крупнее фрейворк тем более он загоняет в жесткие рамки и добавляет оверхеда и для задачи возможно понадобиться много конфигурировать под себя и взять посильнее сервер. Меньшие же фреймворки дают меньше оверхеда и больше гибкости...но для решения задачи придется дописывать. Так что все зависит от задачи и личных предпочтений. Мое мнение - минифреймворки дают недостаточно, а монструозные дают большой оверхед и слишком сковывают. Поэтому я выбираю мидл. 
Еще следует учесть популярность. Для работы лучше взять популярные - найти работу будет легче. Для себя же любой более подходящий под взгляд "как все должно быть устроено".

Comment: Большое спасибо за Ваш ответ! А можете привести хотя бы по паре примеров фреймворков из каждой категории (мини, мидл, и т.д.)?

Comment: @Shadow33 ну если бы я делил...микро: slim, silex, fat-free. середнячки: yii, nette, lavarel и много других. крупняки: zend framework (упор на академичности и адский оверхед). Для себя я выбрал nette за его mvp+компонентный подход+dsl'ы, но я на них не зарабатываю иначе выбрал бы yii или lavarel из-за спроса.

Answer (score 1):

Честно говоря, тут все зависит от проекта... я сейчас работаю над бэкендом и апи, и здесь мы решили только хардкор. Хотя, для каких-то проектов разумнее использовать фреймворк.

Так или иначе, если вы хотите развиваться, я бы вам посоветовал развиваться с Symfony... Тот же Laravel основывается на Symfony. На Symfony так же перевели друпал, пхпбб, а так же другие вещи переводятся на Symfony. Ориентируясь на https://packagist.org : Symfony - объективный лидер, выбранный мировым сообществом, вторым идет Laravel, а Yii&Yii2 очень далеко от них. Это говорит о многом.

Если вы хотите получить реальную квалификацию и возможность работать с любыми рынками (т.е. не ориентироваться только на Россию), я бы советовал работать с Symfony либо Laravel. Конечно, если вы станете продвинутым прогером на Yii2, вы сможете найти свою аудиторию заказчиков, но будете неприятно удивлены тем, что Yii2 совсем не востребованный (в сравнении с S&L) на международном рынке фреймворк. Самое, что интересное, российский рынок в настоящее время догоняет (ну тут уж как может) запад и насыщается Symfony и Laravel.

Т.е. при выборе фреймворка нужно опираться на множество показателей... тут примерно так же, как если бы вы писали сайты сами, как могли, но потом увидели джумлу и решили стать в ней супер-профи, работали с ней лет 5... а потом смотрели, как другим достаются серьезные, интересные и высокооплачиваемые проекты после их 1-2 года серьезной работы с каким-либо фреймворком.